# SVG with width:auto does not affect width of containing anchor tag in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I have some SVG images wrapped in anchor tags. I want the images to have a 25px height and a width of `auto`. This is working fine in modern browsers, but in IE, the width of the anchor tag does not seem to be adjusting to the width of the image. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

**EDIT:** This issue persists even if the anchor tags are changed to divs. It seems to produce the same result regardless of the type of containing element.

**EDIT 2:** Specifying a width on the SVG resolves the issue, but this is not a feasible solution since the SVGs are being pulled in dynamically and there are hundreds of them. Looking for a solution that allows me to specify only the height and have the width scale proportionally.

**EDIT 3:** Thanks to @DipenShah it has been determined that this issue is only present in older builds of IE11.....

```css
a.logo {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:14px 10px 11px;
  border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
a.logo img {
  display:block;
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<a class="logo" href="#">
 <img src="https://svgur.com/i/8H0.svg" />
</a>
<a class="logo" href="#">
 <img src="https://svgur.com/i/8Ex.svg" />
</a>
```

Here's the result I get in IE:
[image]

Comment: Works fine for me even on IE 11. Which version of IE are you using BTW?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with IE, may be some other CSS you are using is overriding default formating in IE.

Comment: If it works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not IE, how would the problem not be with IE? The screenshot above was taken in IE11. I have tested on 3 different computers, the issue is present on all of them, so I'm not sure how it was working for you. I have updated the screenshot to show the exact version of IE I am using. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using IE 11.345.17134.0 and it is working fine.

Comment: Wow. Just tested on my personal computer in 11.345 and it is working.... Gotta love IE, works on some versions of IE11 and doesn't work on others. Someone please kill this browser and take us out of our misery. Well, thanks for the update, guess I'll have to tell my client there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: @DipenShah since bounties are non-refundable, if you want to answer with "IE Sucks," or something along those lines, I will award you the bounty since you helped me determine that the issue only exists in older builds of IE11.

Comment: Sure, I wish SO had such a option exclusively for IE to revoke your bounty so that you don't have to loose you hardly earned SO reps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an issue with older builds of IE. On IE 11.345.17134.0 it is working fine.

[image]